# Non-defined return of sub

Tags: perl, function, return, return-value

How can I avoid that a variable gets touched by a return of a subfunction. I wrote following code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "init";

sub funct{
    my $var;
    #$var = 1;
    return $var if defined $var;
}

my $tmp = funct;

$a = $tmp if defined $tmp;
print "$a\n";
```

and I don't want the value of `$a` be changed from it's initial `init` if `$var` isn't defined in the subfunction.

Where is the error or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return $foo if $bar` is equivalent to `$bar and return $foo`. Therefore, when `$bar` is false, then this statement evaluates to the value of `$bar`. As subroutines return the value of the last executed statement, your sub returns either `$var` if it is defined, or a false value, if not.

You can either go the explicit route, and put another return there:

```
# all branches covered
return $var if defined $var;
return;
```

This is silly, and equivalent to `return $var`.

Now the false value that your sub returns is in fact defined, so it is assigned to `$a`. You could test for truth instead:

```
$a = $tmp if $tmp;
```

… but that opens another can of worms.

---

Return values are extraordinary bad at telling us whether they are the wanted return value, or an error indicator. There are two clean ways around that:

1. Return a second value that tells us whether the function exited OK:

   ```
   sub func {
     my $var;
     return (1, $var) if defined $var;
     return (0);  # not strictly needed
   }

   my ($ok, $tmp) = func();
   $a = $tmp if $ok;
   ```

   (basically, the comma-ok idiom as seen in Golang)
2. Return a container that has to be destructured to obtain the actual return value. A possibility is to either return `undef` (or something false) on error, or a scalar reference to the value when such a value exists:

   ```
   sub func {
     my $var;
     return \$var if defined $var;
     return undef;  # actually not needed
   }

   my $tmp = func();
   $a = $$tmp if defined $tmp;
   ```

   (basically, a `Maybe` type as seen in Haskell)

   Here is a way to use that without obious temp vars:

   ```
   ($a) = map { $_ ? $$_ : () } func(), \$a;
   ```

Comment: Thx! Always great to read such detailed answers. As I am kind of a newbie, this deserves the accepted answer because of the insight I earned. I like the first definition, because it is intuitively understandable.

Comment: I like OP better than `($a) = map { $_ ? $$_ : () } func(), \$a;`, or `($a) = map { defined $_ ? $_ : () } func(), $a;`

Comment: @mpapec That `map` expression is not neccessarily meant to be used. Rather, it is showcasing how this could be generalized. (Actually, it is a bit of Haskell snobbery and highlights similarities between the `Maybe` monad and Perl's scalarrefs. For a monad, we need operations `return: t→t?` which is implemented by the reference operator `\ ` and `bind: t?→(t→u?)→u?`, which can be expressed as `sub bind {my ($x, $f) = @_; $x ? $f->($$x) : undef}`. As `Maybe` is additive, we also have `mzero` (`undef`) and `mplus: t?→t?→t?` which is `sub mplus {(grep $_, @_)[0]}`. …)

Comment: ( … We can also define a `fmap: (t→u)→t?→u?` which lifts a function to the monad level: `sub fmap {my ($x, $f) = @_; $x ? \($f->($$x)) : undef}` which is very similar to `bind`. Throw a few sub prototypes in there, and we could write `fmap {$a = $_[0]} mplus func(), \$a`. When we substitute in the definitions (and do some provable optimizations), we get `\($a = ${ (grep $_, func(), \$a)[0] })` which can also be expressed as the `map` expression in my answer. (Btw, if we see a Perl list as a monad, then `map` is the `bind` for that type).)

Comment: tnx for explanation; while functional style for perl may look tempting it also may move a few eyebrows

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid temporary variable,

```
$a = funct() // $a;
```

Comment: Can you explain this please?
I changed the second-last line with yours and it's not working.

Comment: also change `return $var if defined $var;` with `return $var;`

Answer (score 1):

Running this program in the Perl debugger shows that `$tmp` is set to an empty string, which evaluates to true with the `defined` function. This is why the conditional that sets `$a` evaluates to true:

```
$ perl -d

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `perldoc perldebug' for more help.

use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "init";

sub funct{
    my $var;
    #$var = 1;
    return $var if defined $var;
}

my $tmp = funct;

$a = $tmp if defined $tmp;
print "$a\n";
__END__
main::(-:4):    my $a = "init";

  DB<1> x $a
0  undef

  DB<2> n
main::(-:12):   my $tmp = funct;

  DB<2> x $a
0  'init'

  DB<3> x $tmp
0  undef

  DB<4> n
main::(-:14):   $a = $tmp if defined $tmp;

  DB<4> x $tmp
0  ''
```

To fix, simply `return $var`, without the `if defined $var`. This will set `$tmp` to `undef`

Comment: Thx @Zaid, never used the Debugger. Will try to do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to detect error scenarios by returning `undef`. In addition to @amon's suggestions, you could `die` out of `funct` when an error occurs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "init";

sub funct{
    my $var;
    ...
    if ($something_went_wrong) {
       die 'something bad';
    }
    ...
    return $var;
}

eval {
    $a = funct;
    1;
} or do {
    # log/handle the error in $@
};

print "$a\n";
```